# C++ ADT Set implementation on HashTable (resolving colisions with independent lists)

Tags: c++, set, hashtable, abstract-data-type

As the title says I am trying to implement Set ADT on a Hashtable with independent lists. The thing is I don't know where I'm wrong.

The code I am about to post is taken from a bigger project and I took just the esential parts of it to show you.

SetADT.h:

```
    #pragma once
#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>

#define CAPACITY 10

using namespace std;

template <typename TElement>
class IteratorSet;






template<typename TElement>
class Set {

    class Nod {
    public:
        TElement element;
        Nod* next;

    };

public:

    Set();


    void add(TElement element);


    int size();


    void sterge(TElement element);


    bool cauta(TElement element); 


    friend class IteratorSet<TElement>;
    IteratorSet<TElement> iterator() { return IteratorSet<TElement>(this); }

private:

    int dimensiune;


    typename Set<TElement>::Nod* prim;


    int max;


    Nod** table;


    int hashFunction(TElement element) { return element.hashCode() % max; }


    Nod* set;
};

template<typename TElement>
Set<TElement>::Set()

{
    max = CAPACITATE;
    table = new Nod*[max];
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        table[i] = NULL;
}

template <typename TElement>
void Set<TElement>::add(TElement element)

{
    int pozitie = hashFunction(element);
    Nod* curent = table[pozitie];
    while (curent != NULL && !(element == curent->element))
        curent = curent->next;
    if (curent != NULL)
        return;
    else
    {
        Nod* n = new Nod;
        n->element = element;
        n->next = table[pozitie];
        table[pozitie] = n;
    }
    dimensiune++;
}

template <typename TElement>
int Set<TElement>::size()

{
    return dimensiune;
}

template <typename TElement>
void Set<TElement>::sterge(TElement element)

{
    int pozitie = hashFunction(element);
    Nod* curent = table[pozitie];


    if (table[pozitie] == NULL)
        return;


    if (table[pozitie]->element == element)
    {
        Nod* deSters = table[pozitie];
        table[pozitie] = table[pozitie]->next;
        delete deSters;
        dimensiune--;
        return;
    }


    Nod* elem = table[pozitie];
    while (elem->next != NULL && (elem->next->element) == element)
        elem = elem->next;



    if (elem->next != NULL)
    {
        Nod* deSters = elem->next;
        elem->next = elem->next->next;
        delete deSters;
        dimensiune--;
    }

}

template <typename TElement>
bool Set<TElement>::cauta(TElement element)

{
    int pozitie = hashFunction(element);
    Nod* curent = table[pozitie];
    while (curent != NULL && !(element == curent->element))
        curent = curent->next;
    if (curent != NULL)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}







template<typename TElement>
class IteratorSet {
public:
    IteratorSet(Set<TElement>* m);
    void next();
    bool valid();
    TElement element();
private:
    Set<TElement>* Set;
    typename Set<TElement>::Nod* crt;
};

template<typename TElement>
IteratorSet<TElement>::IteratorSet(Set<TElement>* mul) {
    Set = mul;
    crt = mul->prim;
}

template<typename TElement>
bool IteratorSet<TElement>::valid() {
    return crt != NULL;
}

template<typename TElement>
TElement IteratorSet<TElement>::element() {
    return crt->element;
}

template<typename TElement>
void IteratorSet<TElement>::next() {
    crt = crt->next;
}
```

=======================================================
domain.h (names of Pizzas)

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Pizza {
public:
    Pizza(string namePizza) : namePizza(namePizza) {}
    Pizza() : namePizza("") {}

    string getName() const {
        return namePizza;
    }
    int hashCode()
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
            sum += str[i];
        return sum;
    }
    bool operator == (Pizza& other) {
        return namePizza == other.getName();
    }

private:
    string namePizza;
    string str;
};
```

====================================================
main.cpp:

```
#include "SetADT.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "domain.h"

void show(Set<Pizza>* set) {
    IteratorSet<string> it = set->iterator();
    while (it.valid()) {
        cout << "\t" << it.element().getName() << endl;
        it.next();
    }
}



int main()
{
    Set<Pizza> set;

    Pizza pizza1{ "diavola" };
    Pizza pizza2{ "prosciuto" };

    set.add(pizza1);
    set.add(pizza2);

    show(set);

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to print the objects added to the Set it pops and error and the program stops.

I don't know anywhere else to look to find the problem.

Anyway, if the code sample isn't enough, here the complete project ( has parts of romanian in it )

http://www20.zippyshare.com/v/qKpEcZhr/file.html

Comment: I *really* hope the hashtable is one of the main points of your exercise, or you should use [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) which is the standard library hashmap class.

Comment: yes..that's exactly the task I have to do.. they won't let me use unordered_map or unordered_set

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be, for example, `prim` variable that you use in the iterator, that is initialized to an undefined value. However, code you posted is not compilable, i.e. there are other problems why your code is not working. Did not download your zip file.

Comment: the zip file compiles and the problem is better examples in it

Comment: Could you post plz relevant essentials of your working code, otherwise it is hard to help))